# Django failing to find apps

Tags: python, django

I have been working on a django app on my local computer for some time now and i am trying to move it to a mediatemple container and im having a problem when i try to start up django. it gives me this traceback:

```
application failed to start, starting manage.py fastcgi failed:Traceback
(most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 11, in ?
execute_manager(settings) File
"/home/58626/data/python/lib/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 340,
in execute_manager utility.execute() File
"/home/58626/data/python/lib/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 295,
in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv) File
"/home/58626/data/python/lib/django/core/management/base.py", line 192, in
run_from_argv self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__) File
"/home/58626/data/python/lib/django/core/management/base.py", line 210, in
execute translation.activate('en-us') File
"/home/58626/data/python/lib/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line
73, in activate return real_activate(language) File
"/home/58626/data/python/lib/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line
43, in delayed_loader return g['real_%s' % caller](*args, **kwargs) File
"/home/58626/data/python/lib/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line
209, in activate _active[currentThread()] = translation(language) File
"/home/58626/data/python/lib/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line
198, in translation default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
File "/home/58626/data/python/lib/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py",
line 181, in _fetch app = getattr(__import__(appname[:p], {}, {},
[appname[p+1:]]), appname[p+1:]) AttributeError: 'module' object has no
attribute 'web'
```

The name of the first app is "web".

Comment: When you try to start up Django; does this mean when you try to start up **the development sever**?

Comment: Did you already make sure your settings file is taking into account the new location?

Comment: Can you use UpperCase Letters for I and I'm?  It's hard to read when you don't use your Shift Key to make it look like Proper English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps I would take would be

1. Run the dev server on your Media Template instance. If that runs successfully, it obviously is an error with your apache/nginx/whaever setup.
2. I dont have experience running apps as FCGI, which it looks to em you are trying to do. It looks to me that somehow when Fcgi runs, it is unable to find your apps. So this is possibly a PYTHONPATH issue. Log/Print sys.path from your fcgi script and look there.

Comment: +1: Very likely PYTHONPATH isn't right.  Often local computer development is all in a jumble in directories that work "by luck".