# Move a Pinax project

Tags: pinax

(Cross post from Pinax Users Google group -- I figured it would be useful to have this question on here as well.)

I'm a bit stuck. My projects work fine when I run them on the original machine I create them on, but I get an error when I move them to another machine. I'm trying to use hosted version control to manage a project between two computers, but it only works on the machine I create it on. I'm just trying to get the project base "zero" to run on both machines. Here's the console output I'm getting when I run manage.py runserver:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 27, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line()
  File "/home/loren/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 352, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/loren/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 306, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/loren/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 192, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/loren/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 210, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/home/loren/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 73, in activate
    return real_activate(language)
  File "/home/loren/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 43, in delayed_loader
    return g['real_%s' % caller](*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/loren/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 209, in activate
    _active[currentThread()] = translation(language)
  File "/home/loren/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 198, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/loren/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 181, in _fetch
    app = getattr(__import__(appname[:p], {}, {}, [appname[p+1:]]), appname[p+1:])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'messages'
```

I expect that this has something to do with my pythonpath, but I'm just too new to this to know where to look. I dug up this thread, but I couldn't find a solution in it:
[Django failing to find apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056675/django-failing-to-find-apps)

Help would be great!

Comment: Figured it out -- I was using the wrong version of Pinax. (built it in 0.9, but I was trying to run it in 0.7.) Also, be sure to clone a project so that you download the required modules automatically.

Comment: Please add that as an answer instead of "Solved ->".